# How to Use ImageSlideshow library with sdwebimage library

Tags: ios, swift, slideshow, sdwebimage

I am try to use [imageSlideShow](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow) library and for load image, i use [SdwebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) library ,but i don't know how to use together

[imageSlideShow](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow) in section `How to use` ,saying you can use `AlamofireImage`,`sdwebImage`,`kingFisher` library  and example this code:

```html
slideshow.setImageInputs([
  ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "myImage"))!,
  ImageSource(image: UIImage(named: "myImage2"))!,
  AlamofireSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432679963831-2dab49187847?w=1080"),
  KingfisherSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432679963831-2dab49187847?w=1080"),
  ParseSource(file: PFFile(name:"image.jpg", data:data))
])
```

but don't explain or example for `SdWebImage`.

My question is how to use`SdWebImage` for `slideshow.setImageInputs([])`

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, add this one into your Pod file:

```
pod "ImageSlideshow/SDWebImage"
```

Run `pod install`

And now, you can create an array of ImageSource for your slideshow like this:

```
let ea = [SDWebImageSource(url: URL(string: "http://mutfakustam.com/resimler/tarifler/et-tavuk-yemekleri/biberli-et-kavurmasi-136-1.jpg")!)]
```

And set image inputs of your slideshow:

```
slideshow.setImageInputs(ea)
```